# Able to ping but unable to access web server running in guest VM

Tags: linux, networking

In my network setup below, I'm able to ping guest vm1 from my external client machine. But, I can't access apache web server running in guest vm1 from my external client. I'm able to ping after updating the routing table in my physical router to route traffic for guest vm network but accessing webserver doesn't work. Please help to figure out the issue. Hypervisor is KVM and used open vSwitch for for bridging. [image]

Comment: seems firewall related...but then it is your infra-structure. We wont be able to help much.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that the .1.6 client has ICMP connectivity to the .100.1 VM, but cannot send a TCP SYN port 80 packet there. Or at least, client never hears the SYN ACK.

Sounds like inbound NAT filtering, especially if VM1 can do outbound ping or TCP connects to your windows client. Verify with `tcpdump` on the debian host and also on VM1.

Comment: ICMP connectivity is there but seems TCP is not working.As you suggested, I will look into tcpdump on debian host and VM1. Thank you.

Comment: I ran tcpdump on router VM and VM1. The tcpdump of both shows only one packet that is coming from external client. There is no response from VM1. I've checked the firewall of router VM and VM1. They accept all connections by default. There is no rule to reject any connection.